React Bootstrap - display 2.5 items visible at a time
I am using React Bootstrap's Carousel component in my NextJS project. Right now everything works except the fact that in mobile, am displaying only one slide at a time.
But i am trying to improve the UX by displaying 2 items and half of the third slide visible at a time. The reason for 2.5 items is because this will let the user know that there are more items in the carousel as am not displaying any arrows.
Already googled for a solution. But not successful in finding anything that helps.
Here’s a demo of what am trying to achieve:
screenshot
This is like 1.5 items. Am trying to achieve 2.5 items

Please see [ask] and take the [tour], Your post needs improvement.
